# How do I get rid of errors and warnings in /etc/mail.log pertaining to a defunct mailman installation?

Tags: server, email, postfix, mailman

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server that at one point in time was set up (not by me) to run *GNU mailman*, using *Postfix* as the MTA.

I no longer run any mailinglists on this server, and have ‐ to the best of my ability ‐ tried to remove and purge *Gnu mailman* from the server by running these commands:

```
sudo apt remove mailman
sudo apt autoremove mailman
sudo apt purge mailman
sudo apt autoremove --purge mailman
```

This removes mailman and some (most?) configuration and data files, but when I look in the Postfix log (`/var/log/mail.log`), I get these about every five minutes:

```
[…]: error: open database /var/lib/mailman/data/aliases.db: No such file or directory
[…]: warning: hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases is unavailable. open database /var/lib/mailman/data/aliases.db: No such file or directory
[…]: warning: hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases: lookup of 'root' failed
```

I understand why I get them, since purging *GNU mailman* deleted all those files.

I am pretty sure that the program that requests these files is *Postfix*, as running:

```
sudo service postfix status
```

… produces the same three lines of errors and warnings. However, I am unable to figure out what it is that makes *Postfix* want to open these files.

Restarting postfix:

```
sudo systemctl restart postfix
```

… cleans out the errors, but only temporary. After about five minutes, they are back when I check status.

The question is this: How to I get rid of these errors and warnings (without reinstalling the no longer needed application)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this out by searching for the filname in and below `/etc`.

It looks like the reason *Postfix* tries to access the files `/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases` and  `/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases.db` stems from this line in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` (the *Postfix* main configuration file):

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
```

Changed it to:

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
```

… and restarted *Postfix*.

As far as I able to tell, this fixes it. (I used to get these log entries every five minutes. It is now thirty minutes since I restarted *Postfix* and there is *no* new log entries about "mailman".)

Answer (score 0):

There may be some processes still running that are trying to write to those locations. Use fuser to figure out what they are.

As per the logs themselves, Check /etc/rsyslog.conf and look for a mailman entry.

Comment: Thanks, but fuser just says "Specified filename … does not exist" (true, but not helpful), and `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and subdirectories have no mailman entry. I am pretty sure that the *process* that requests those locations is *postfix* (and have updated the question to indicate that). However, I need to know what setting makes *Postfix* do that, and remove it.